# Retrieving items from shopping cart in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a shopping cart that is build with Javascript. The code is fairly simple, the javascript code gets the information from the class the clicked button is in and gets added to the shopping cart. Like this:

```js
function addToCartClicked(event) {
  var button = event.target
  var shopItem = button.parentElement.parentElement
  var title = shopItem.getElementsByClassName('Product-info-title')[0].innerText
  var price = shopItem.getElementsByClassName('Product-info-prijs')[0].innerText
  var imageSrc = shopItem.getElementsByClassName('Product-image')[0].src
  addItemToCart(title, price, imageSrc)
  updateCartTotal()
}

function addItemToCart(title, price, imageSrc) {
  var cartRow = document.createElement('div')
  cartRow.classList.add('cart-row')
  var cartItems = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-items')[0]
  var cartItemNames = cartItems.getElementsByClassName('Winkelmand-beschrijving')
  for (var i = 0; i < cartItemNames.length; i++) {
    if (cartItemNames[i].innerText == title) {
      alert('Dit product is al in uw winkelmand.')
      return
    }
  }
  var cartRowContents = `
    <button class="delete-btn" type="button" name="button"></button>
    <div class="Winkelmand-image">
        <img src="${imageSrc}" alt="" />
    </div>
    <span class="Winkelmand-beschrijving">${title}</span>
    <button class="minus-btn" type="button" onclick="increment(this, false)">-</button><div class="hoeveel">1</div><button class="plus-btn" type="button" onclick="increment(this, true)">+</button>
    <div class="Winkelmand-prijs">${price}</div>`
  cartRow.innerHTML = cartRowContents
  cartItems.append(cartRow)
  cartRow.getElementsByClassName('delete-btn')[0].addEventListener('click', removeCartItem)
}
```

Now I want to know what is in the shopping cart from the server side. So that the order can be added to the database.

Note that this is not a project that will ever go live on the internet, this is for personal use.

Comment: What's your question? All you've done is tell us about your work so far, and then described a new requirement. It's unclear what issue you're facing in achieving it. What have you researched or tried so far? What goes wrong? What don't you understand? None of this is clear.

Comment: @adyson, Hi thanks for your answer. I tried getting session information on the server side, but this is not possible since these are limited to the client side. I also tried getting HTML information to my C#, but with no success. I know I am not 100% clear here, but I honestly don't know how to do this. I couldn't find anything helpful so I tried asking here.

Comment: In any web page, if you want to send data to the server you have to make a HTTP request. Browsers can initiate a HTTP request in 3 basic ways: 1) navigating to a new URL (by user typing it into the address bar, or clicking on a link, or by some javascript code doing it), 2) submitting a form (by user clicking submit button, or by some javascript triggering it), 3) making an ajax request. So if you need to know the shopping cart contents on the server, your browser must first send it there. I'd guess in this situation that AJAX is probably the most suitable option for you.